# Failed to get records when matching c# DateTime value against Date value in sql

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a date column in a database table.

[image]

I'm using a LINQ expression that search records using today's date against this DOB column.

```
DateTime searchDate = DateTime.Now;
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> cntExpression = p => p.DOB.HasValue && p.DOB == searchDate
```

Now, When I try to execute this expression then no record is returned. The reason is that I am passing 'DateTime' value in LINQ expression and the DOB column in the database table is of 'Date' type. So it's trying to match a datetime value against a date only value.

I already tried to use:

```
DateTime searchDate = DateTime.Now;
```

but it didn't solved the problem.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't type supposed to be datetime2 in SQL?

Comment: nomail in sql the type is date.

Comment: That is the thing. `date` type only holds the date(YYYY-MM-DD) while you're also trying to use time. Change `date` to `datetime2` and I belive it will resolve your issue. Check out this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes

Answer (score 0):

You say that the field in the database is of type `DATE` which doesn't contain any time information. You're trying to search against `DateTime.Now` which will contain the time. Try searching against `DateTime.Today` instead and removing the time portion of any other dates being searched by using `searchDate.Date`

Comment: Mike D. the problem is that I not using today's date only, it can be an earlier date or a future date also.

Comment: use `searchDate.Date` to set the time portion to 00:00:00. .NET doesn't have an equivalent data type that only stores the date portion so I assume using midnight will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take just the date part of the searchDate (at the end or anywhere before)

```
DateTime searchDate = DateTime.Now;
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> cntExpression = p => p.DOB.HasValue && p.DOB == searchDate.Date
```

Comment: Marko Juvančič I tried this but problem remains the same.